# 3D Interpolation Methods for Motion Capture Data

Tags: c++, opengl, interpolation

I'm currently doing a project whereby I want to interpolate between the ending frame of one motion capture file (BVH) and the beginning frame of a second motion capture file. Each file consists of a dancing figure, both in the same dance style.

Prior to the interpolation step, I intend to transform the root position of the second mocap file to the position of the root of the second mocap file.

I've looked at using the Chordal or Centripetal Catmul-Rom spline for interpolation as well as Cubic splines. At a high-level, we define the controls points for the interpolation function as the position of each joint/segment in the first and second file. The interpolation function would then interpolate between each segment.

I wanted to know of any concerns that I should be aware of prior to programming this piece of functionality. I'm concerned about the way in which the interpolation should be conducted because of the dependency between parent and child segments. Is it possible for this to be handled effectively (to mean produce a smooth transition between two frames)?

Comment: I am afraid that interpolation like that will lead to non constant bone sizes ... better would be determine the plane of rotation between bone frame s and linearly interpolate the rotation angle in bone local coordinate system ...

Comment: I'd recently read that usually rotations in Euler Angles are specified in the motion samples for each segment in the file aside from the root. I'm planning on using Slerp to do quaternion interpolation across each segment.

Comment: yep in standard BVH files I saw you got euler angles so just lienarly interpolate each angle ...